# Manipulate a string in a linq query whilst converting to a new type

Tags: linq

I am taking a grouped set of results and converting them to a new type in one statement:

```
// Remove availability for duplicates and only check "available" records
var filterdResults =
    from x in results
    group x by (x.HcaName, x.HcaBranch, x.HcaArea, x.HcaType, x.PositionType, x.StartDate, x.StartTime, x.EndDate, x.EndTime, x.Hours, x.Type, x.Notes) into g
    select new HcaAvailabilityExport
    {
        HcaName = g.Key.HcaName,
        HcaBranch = g.Key.HcaBranch,
        HcaArea = g.Key.HcaArea,
        HcaType = g.Key.HcaType,
        PositionType = g.Key.PositionType,
        StartDate = g.Key.StartDate,
        StartTime = g.Key.StartTime,
        EndDate = g.Key.EndDate,
        EndTime = g.Key.EndTime,
        Hours = g.Key.Hours,
        Type = g.Key.Type,
        Notes = g.Key.Notes
    };
```

On this particular line

`HcaName = g.Key.HcaName` the resulting string would be something like `Mr Joe Bloggs` or `Mrs Jane Doe`.

What I'd like to do with this string is convert the output by removing the name of the title, add a comma and reverse the first name and surname. E.g. `Doe, Jane` or `Bloggs, Joe`.

The closest I have managed to get it myself is

`HcaName = string.Concat(g.Key.HcaName.Replace(" "," ,").Split(" ").Reverse().Take(2))`

The output looks like this though: `,Doe,Jane` or `,Bloggs,Joe`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Concat` use `Join` like so:

`string.Join(", ", g.Key.HcaName.Split(' ').Reverse().Take(2))`

Comment: Legend. That really had my brain ticking!